# Application displays correctly on a 150% scaled monitor but not on a 100% one

Tags: c#, .net, scaling, dpi

I am currently developing an application in c# with .NET Framework 4.7
I have a problem with DPI scaling. On my computer I have two monitors, one with 150% scaling and another one with 100%. I added this code in my app manifest file:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
  <asmv3:application  xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

And it works perfectly fine.

[image: What is looks like when correctly displayed]

i take the exe file and all its dependecies, take it to another computer who as only one screen with 100% scaling and the application doesn't look as it should do.

[image: What it looks when not correctly displayed]

I hope you guys have a solution for me I am struggling since two days with this problem...

Comment: What type of application is this? [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee308410(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: Can you show the xaml of the message box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, like every time I post my problem I figure out the solution a few moments later.

I removed the manifest file from the application and changed the `AutoScaleMode` propertie to `Dpi` instead of `Font` for every form in my application.

And now it works like a charm.

Comment: I guess this a form or "rubber duck debugging"? Good job figuring it out! :)